# Read several lines (with spaces) from file and pass it as parameters to a single command

Tags: bash

I would like to read many lines from a file (or the standard input) and convert it to parameters for a command in bash.
The input would be:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
```

and what I want to have is:

```
$ command "line 1" "line 2" "line 3" ...
```

I've googled the problem but didn't find any solution. The point is that lines may have spaces so at the end they must be into quotation marks.

Comment: Create an array holding the parameters. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically **5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**

Comment: `mapfile -t lines < file.txt; command "${lines[@]}"`

Comment: This solution works fine! I didn't know this mapfile command. Thanks :-) !